# How to make a Linq XML join With attributes on different elements

Tags: c#, linq, attributes, linq-to-xml, element

Ok, sorry but i'm note sure that my question is very clear.

```
<DATA>
   <USERS>
      <USER USER_ID="344351">
         <NAME>John</NAME>
         <FIRST_NAME>Wick</FIRST_NAME>
      </USER>

      <USER>
      ...
      </USER>
   </USERS>

   <OFFICES>
      <OFFICES_USER USER_ID="344351">
        <OFFICE>
          <ROOM_ID>B321</ROOM_ID>
          <ROOM_TYPE>D</ROOM_TYPE>
        </OFFICE>
      </OFFICES_USER>

      <OFFICES_USER USER_ID="345251">
        <OFFICE>
          <ROOM_ID>C340</ROOM_ID>
          <ROOM_TYPE>D</ROOM_TYPE>
        </OFFICE>
      </OFFICES_USER>
   </OFFICES>

</DATA>
```

Heres my code to retrieve some data :

```
List<C_USER> L = (from el in userxml.Descendants("USER")
                  orderby (string)el.Element("NAME")
                  select new C_USER()
                         {
                          name = (string)el.Element("NAME").Value,
                          fname = (string)el.Element("FIRST_NAME").Value,
                          office_room = ???,
                         }).ToList();
```

C_USER is a class containing name, fname, office_room.

I want to get the room id by matching attributes USER_ID from the element USER and in the element OFFICE.

I'm quite new to C# and LinQ so please forgive me :)

The result would be :
name : wick
fname : John
office_room : B321

I tried with descendants but i didn't succeed to extract the ROOM_ID (2 descendants)

thanks you !

Comment: Yes, and as you said i get object reference error as i realize that the XML contains olds records, so my first USER as not been found...

Comment: Check now, it won't throw any error even if you don't have any matching user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this :

```
office_room =(from offices in userxml.Descendants("OFFICES")
              from office in offices.Descendants("OFFICE") 
              where offices.Attribute("USER_ID").Value == el.Attribute("USER_ID").Value
              select office.Element("ROOM_ID").Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Hi ! I cannot test this answer because strangely, VStudio underline the select instruction saying that it cannot convert a IEnumerable<String> to string.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer method syntax, you can do it like this:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"YourXML.xml");
var result = xdoc.Descendants("USER")
      .Select(x => 
    {
        var first = x.Document.Root.Descendants("OFFICE")
                     .FirstOrDefault(o => (string)o.Parent.Attribute("USER_ID") == 
                                          (string)x.Attribute("USER_ID"));
        return new C_USER
         {
            name = (string)x.Element("NAME"),
            fname = (string)x.Element("FIRST_NAME"),
            office_room = first != null ? (string)first.Element("ROOM_ID") : String.Empty
         };
    });
```

**Steps:**
1. Fetching `name` & `fname` is pretty straight forward, as we are fetching them from descendants of `USER`.
2. `x` holds the descendants of `USER`, so first we need to go back to Root, which I am doing using `x.Document.Root` and finally fetching descendants of `OFFICE`. Since we need to match `USER_ID` I am using `FirstOrDefault` to filter out the same.
3. Finally fetching the `Room_ID` from collection retrieved in Step 2.

Please note, you may get `object reference error`, if no `USER_ID` matches in Users & Offices since `FirstOrDefault` will return null in that case.